# Configurar CakePHP para enviar emails pelo gmail

Tags: php, cakephp, envio-de-email, gmail

Estou tentando configurar o [cakephp](/questions/tagged/cakephp) para enviar emails através do [gmail](/questions/tagged/gmail), já fiz algumas pesquisas e ainda não tive êxito no resultado, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No seu arquivo `app/Config/email.php` você precisará criar a classe `EmailConfig`.

O arquivo `app/Config/email.php.default` é um exemplo de como ele deve ficar.

Você deverá criar uma nova configuração chamada [gmail](/questions/tagged/gmail) com o seguinte código

```
public $gmail = array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'seu@gmail.com', // seu email no gmail
    'password' => 'senha', // sua senha no gmail
    'transport' => 'Smtp'
);
```

Para conexões [tls](/questions/tagged/tls) você precisará incluir `'tls' => true` na sua configuração;

Answer (score 4):

Se o seu cakephp for 2.3.0 ou superior use:

```
public $gmail = array(
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'tls' => true
);
```

Veja que ele usa o tls=>true, para versão anterior use:

```
public $gmail = array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'transport' => 'Smtp'
);
```

Isso na classe /app/Config/email.php conforme documentação do cakephp:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html

Comment: irei testar, valeu.

Comment: Não esqueça de  colocar a config na classe ao chamar $Email = new CakeEmail(); $Email->config('gmail');